# How to get all previous print in Python

Tags: python, stringio

I'm currently using some functions to store all `print` in Python

And it get all `print` **AFTER** the function has finished

Here is a sample snippet

```
import io
import sys
import time
import traceback

def return_std(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        old_stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = buffer = io.StringIO()
        try:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            print(traceback.format_exc())
        finally:
            sys.stdout = old_stdout
            body = buffer.getvalue()
            buffer.close()
        return body
    return wrapper

@return_std
def some_useful_function():
    print('so this line is executed at ' + time.strftime('%X'))
    time.sleep(5)

print('program execute at ' + time.strftime('%X'))
std_of_some_useful_function = some_useful_function()
print(std_of_some_useful_function)
print('but we can not know if it succeeded or failed before ' + time.strftime('%X'))
```

output

```
program execute at 11:11:11
so this line is executed at 11:11:11

but we can not know if it succeeded or failed before 11:11:16
```

This way captures all `print` and error in `some_useful_function`, and stores it as the function return. But `print` will not show **BEFORE** this function has finished

How should I modify the wrapper `return_std`, so I can see the output at `11:11:11` instantly (like it was really printed), and get all previous `print` stored at `11:11:16`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a subclass of [io.StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) and override the `write()` method so that it writes to a saved version of `sys.stdout` aswell as writing to it's internal buffer

```
class SavedStdOut(io.StringIO):

    def __init__(self, stdout):
        super().__init__()
        self.stdout = stdout

    def write(self, s: str):
        self.stdout.write(s)
        return super().write(s)
```

The class then writes to the passed file and saves the written data

```
foo = SavedStdOut(sys.stdout)
foo.write('Hello\n')  # Hello
print('Buffer:', foo.getvalue())  # Buffer: Hello
```

A complete example

```
import io
import sys
import time
import traceback


class SavedStdOut(io.StringIO):

    def __init__(self, stdout):
        super().__init__()
        self.stdout = stdout

    def write(self, s: str):
        self.stdout.write(s)
        return super().write(s)


def return_std(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        sys.stdout = buffer = SavedStdOut(sys.stdout)
        try:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            print(traceback.format_exc())
        finally:
            sys.stdout = buffer.stdout
            body = buffer.getvalue()
            buffer.close()
        return body
    return wrapper


@return_std
def some_useful_function():
    print('so this line is executed at ' + time.strftime('%X'))
    time.sleep(5)


print('program execute at ' + time.strftime('%X'))
std_of_some_useful_function = some_useful_function()
print('saved stdout:', std_of_some_useful_function)
print('but we can not know if it succeeded or failed before ' + time.strftime('%X'))
```

Output:

```
program execute at 03:52:01
so this line is executed at 03:52:01  # Printed as soon as print() is called
saved stdout: so this line is executed at 03:52:01

but we can not know if it succeeded or failed before 03:52:06
```

Comment: Thanks, Iain. You helped me and prefectly solved my problem. Your script functions well even if error occurs. I want to accept two answers, but stackoverflow does not allow it.

Comment: @dacianPeng. Lain 's answer is better than mine. If you can unaccept my answer and upvote Lian's, would be awesome

Comment: let's be awesome

Answer (score 1):

Not convinced that whatever you are trying to do is a good idea but you can do it like so.

Create a `my_print` class with `__call__` operator and overwrite the `builtins.print` method with your class like this.

```
class MyPrint():

    def __init__(self):
        self.__buffer = io.StringIO()
        self.__old_print = __builtin__.print

    def getvalue(self):
        return self.__buffer.getvalue()

    def close(self):
        self.__buffer.close()
        __builtin__.print = self.__old_print

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__buffer.write(args[0])
        self.__old_print(*args, **kwargs)

def return_std(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        my_print = MyPrint()
        __builtin__.print = my_print
        try:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            print(traceback.format_exc())
        finally:
            body = my_print.getvalue()
            my_print.close()
        return body
    return wrapper

@return_std
def some_useful_function():
    print('so this line is executed at ' + time.strftime('%X'))
    time.sleep(1)

print('program execute at ' + time.strftime('%X'))
std_of_some_useful_function = some_useful_function()
print(std_of_some_useful_function)
print('but we can not know if it succeeded or failed before ' + time.strftime('%X'))
```

Comment: Thanks, Ajinkya. You helped me and prefectly solved my problem. Your script functions well even if error occurs.

In my project, the `some_useful_function` is part of another decorator, which emails some scheduled functions' debug info. And the email decorator can be added to any function, so I can get a notifying email when an assigned task (function) is done or break.

But sometimes the task lasts too long to wait, and I'm eager to know what happened. Unfortunately, I'm to check nothing in log before receiving email. Now I can check the output while task running, thanks!

Comment: @DacianPeng Consider using `import logging` instead of using print statements. It allows you to `addHandler()` to add capabilities like sending email notifications.

Comment: Good idea, I'll explore the built-in `logging` further. Thanks!